# Generate series of week intervals for given month

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series, weekday, generate-series

In a Postgres 9.1 database, I am trying to generate a series of weeks for a given month but with some constraints. I need all weeks to start on Monday and get cut when they start or end in another month.

Example:

For February, 2013 I want to generate a series like this:

```
         start
------------------------
2013-02-01 00:00:00+00
2013-02-04 00:00:00+00
2013-02-11 00:00:00+00
2013-02-18 00:00:00+00
2013-02-25 00:00:00+00
```

The query that I have now looks like this:

```
SELECT GREATEST(date_trunc('week', dates.d),
                date_trunc('month',dates.d)) as start
FROM generate_series(to_timestamp(1359676800),to_timestamp(1362095999), '1 week') as dates(d)
```

This query gets me the first 4 weeks but it's missing the week from the 25th. Is it possible to get the last week?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select
    greatest(date_trunc('week', dates.d), date_trunc('month',dates.d)) as start
from generate_series('2013-02-01'::date, '2013-02-28', '1 day') as dates(d)
group by 1
order by 1
```

Answer (score 15):

```
SELECT generate_series(date_trunc('week', date '2013-02-01' + interval '6 days')
                     , date_trunc('week', date '2013-02-01' + interval '1 month - 1 day')
                     , interval '1 week')::date AS day
UNION  SELECT date '2013-02-01'
ORDER  BY 1;
```

This variant does not need a subselect, `GREATEST` or `GROUP BY` and only generates the required rows. Simpler, faster. It's cheaper to `UNION` one row.

- Add 6 days to the *first day of the month* before `date_trunc('week', ...)` to compute the **first Monday of the month**.
- Add 1 month and subtract 1 day before `date_trunc('week', ...)` to get the **last Monday of the month**.
  This can conveniently be stuffed into a single `interval` expression: `'1 month - 1 day'`
- `UNION` (*not* `UNION ALL`) the first day of the month to add it unless it's already included as Monday.
- Note that `date` + `interval` results in `timestamp`, which is the optimum here. Detailed explanation:

  - [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/46499873#46499873)

#### Automation

You can provide the start of the date series in a CTE:

```
WITH t(d) AS (SELECT date '2013-02-01')  -- enter 1st of month once
SELECT generate_series(date_trunc('week', d + interval '6 days')
                     , date_trunc('week', d + interval '1 month - 1 day')
                     , interval '1 week')::date AS day
FROM   t
UNION  SELECT d FROM t
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Or wrap it into a simple SQL function for convenience with repeated calls:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_week_starts_this_month(date)
  RETURNS SETOF date AS
$func$
SELECT generate_series(date_trunc('week', $1 + interval '6 days')
                     , date_trunc('week', $1 + interval '1 month - 1 day')
                     , interval '1 week')::date AS day
UNION
SELECT $1
ORDER  BY 1
$func$  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_week_starts_this_month('2013-02-01');
```

You would pass the date for the first day of the month, but it works for *any* date. You the first day and all Mondays for the following month.