# POSTGRES transpose week columns into rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, unpivot, generate-series

My forecast table stores the current week, and then forecasted amounts for 26 weeks out:

```
CREATE TABLE forecast_listings (
   product    integer NOT NULL
 , current_week_date date 
 , weekplus0  integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
 , weekplus1  integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
 , weekplus2  integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
 , weekplus3  integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
 , weekplus4  integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
 -- etc
 , weekplus24 integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
 , weekplus25 integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

For example forecasting a single item, I select a single row with the most recent `current_week_date` and then look at relative weeks.

```
SELECT
unnest(
    array[
    to_char(week_current_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
    to_char(week_current_date + interval '1 weeks', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
    to_char(week_current_date + interval '2 weeks', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
    to_char(week_current_date + interval '3 weeks', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
    to_char(week_current_date + interval '4 weeks', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    -- ...all the way to 25
    ]
) AS "Week",
unnest(
    array[
    weekplus0,
    weekplus1, 
    weekplus2, 
    weekplus3,
    weekplus4
    -- ...all the way to 25
    ]
) AS "Count"
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM forecast_listings 
    WHERE product_id = 1
    ORDER BY week_current_date DESC
    LIMIT 1
) as row
```

I would like to do this with Postgres, essentially fetching a row and transposing each weeks number to a row with a date column and count column:

```
week, count
2017-10-01,100
2017-10-08,200
2017-10-15,150
etc.
```

Comment: Please clarify. `asin`, `valid_as_of` (you mean `current_week_date`?), and `weekcurrent`(`weekplus0`?) are not in your table definition. And what's with the *"month"* in the title? I lent a hand and replaced the list of columns with a `CREATE TABLE` statement we can work with. And some syntax fixes. Provide some sample values and your version of Postgres. I am pretty sure there is an elegant solution ...

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter yeah i have slimmed the question down to a simple what is a better way to transpose this weekly data from column values into separated rows.

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT to_char(f.week_current_date + interval '1 week' * w, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
     , arr[w+1]
FROM  (
   SELECT week_current_date
        , ARRAY[weekplus0, weekplus1, weekplus2, weekplus3] AS arr  -- add all 26
   FROM   forecast_listings
   WHERE  product_id = 1
   ORDER  BY week_current_date DESC NULLS LAST  -- ?
   LIMIT  1
   ) f
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL generate_series(0, 25) w;
```

The key feature is a `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` to `generate_series()` to generate the desired rows. Use an [ARRAY constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) like you already had in the subquery. The generated index `w` is used to add weeks to the base date as well as to access respective array items. Take note of a lurking off-by-1 error, since Postgres array indexes are 1-based by default. Related:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)
- [How to unpivot a table in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25625342/how-to-unpivot-a-table-in-postgresql/25627588#25627588)
- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)
- [Normalize array subscripts for 1-dimensional array so they start with 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011569/normalize-array-subscripts-for-1-dimensional-array-so-they-start-with-1)
- [Generate series of week intervals for given month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437940/generate-series-of-week-intervals-for-given-month/15438508#15438508)

Since `week_current_date` does seem to allow NULL values, you may want to use  `ORDER  BY week_current_date DESC`**`NULLS LAST`** to sort rows with NULL last which would otherwise be on top. See:

- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)